# How to put a figure in rectangular box

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put the figure in a rectangular box whose sides are two axes and two straight lines parallel to the axes. Also x and y should be written at the bottom (in middle) of the corresponding axis. Please modify the code:

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.04,yscale=0.08,domain=0.125:100,samples=400]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (150,0) node[below] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,65) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[red] plot (\x,{50-0.5*\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An example of the box is given herewith
[image]

Comment: Why not using `pgfplots`? There the axis is a box (right out of the box ;-).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I don't know how to do that. I modified the code as \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.04,yscale=0.08,domain=0.125:100,samples=400]
    \draw (0,0) -- (150,0) node[below] {$x$};
  \draw (150,0) -- (150,65) node[below] ;
    \draw (0,0) -- (0,65) node[left] {$y$};
  \draw (150,65) -- (0,65) node[below] ;
    \draw[red] plot (\x,{50-0.5*\x});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
But don't know how to put the symbols  x and yat the bottom (in middle) of the corresponding axis

Comment: Tikz data visualization provides a [scientific axes] option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pgfplots` it is as simple as

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,domain=0:10]
  \addplot[mark=none,color=red]{50-0.5*x};
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, as `pgfplots` is based on `tikz`, you continue to have access to all features of `tikz`.